# Simple Sql statement in Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

```
Table: Users
ID123   John Doo
ID345   John Woo

Table: Contacts
ID123  Microsoft  johnd@microsoft.com  +1-234567
ID345  Private Co johnw@privateco.com  +9-654321 
ID345  IBM        johnw@ibm.com        +1-456789
```

Run SQL:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, CompanyName 
FROM Users INNER JOIN Contacts ON User.Id = Contacts.UserId
WHERE (FirstName = 'John' AND CompanyName = 'Microsoft') OR CompanyName = 'IBM'
```

We get these results:

```
John   Doo   Microsoft
John   Woo   IBM
```

Pretty simple so far, right? 
Now, let's write this in C# Lambda or Linq:

```
conn.Users.Where(user => 
(user.FirstName=="John" && user.Contacts.Any(contact => contact.CompanyName=="Microsoft"))
|| user.Contacts.Any(contact => contact.CompanyName=="IBM"))
.Select(......);
```

My question is, what do we put in the `Select()` statement at the end to achieve the same result set?

Comment: Use anonymous objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON User.Id = Contacts.UserId` indicates that you've got a `1..*` relationship from `User` to `Contact`.

That means with `Linq`, you must start by querying `Contacts`, rather than `Users`, as the result will have a row per contact, rather than a row per user.

Something like this will work:

```
conn.Contacts
     .Where(c => c.CompanyName == "IBM" ||
                (c.CompanyName == "Microsoft" && c.User.FirstName == "John"))
     .Select(c => new { c.User.FirstName, c.User.LastName, c.CompanyName })
```

Comment: You are correct in this small example, however, in my case when distinct and paging kicks in, I can't change the centric EF model, as it will not give me the right counts.

Comment: @Tom Can you elaborate a bit? What are you running the distinct/paging on? Paging will not work when querying `Users` (imagine you set paging to 10, and one user had 100 contacts?). Please edit the question to include a practical example of the problem you're having, so answers can be more accurate :)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I can't expose the whole scale of the project. But I am reconsidering the way how I use this query to achieve what I am trying to do. I will accept your answer and think further what to do with my case.